# Why does typescript not issue an error on missing semicolon at the end of statement

Tags: typescript

For example, if I use following statements, I see no compiler error.

```
public SomeFunction() {

    this.privateFunction() (no semi colon here)
}
```

or

```
public SomeFunction() {

    this.privateFunction();
}
```

I am wondering if semicolon at the end of every statement is really required?

Comment: Is there any way to enforce compiler to issue an error on missing semicolon at the end of every statement?

Comment: Why not just set up a linter like Eslint and enforce a semicolon rule?

Answer (score 9):

Semicolons are optional in JavaScript - TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, ergo, semicolons are optional in TypeScript. That said, you will still run into issues with ASI like you would with JavaScript if you don't know where semicolons will be automatically placed.

Comment: Sorry but this is just a often repeated myth. There are no ASI issues. This is just dogma that has been ingrained in languages dating back to The C language where semicolons were in fact required.

Comment: I'm in agreement with @RickO'Shea. With good coding practices, there is almost no chance you'd run into ASI issues.

Comment: I disagree @RickO'Shea, Geoffrey Abdallah is completely correct; semicolons are optional, but ASI issues DO exist. So they can't be dismissed as dogma. There are many examples, but you're "There are no..." statement can be disproven with just one example, like this issue in Bootstrap with minification:  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3057

Douglas Crockford recommends using semicolons; as do Google's JS guidelines:
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Semicolons

Comment: TypeScript per v1.8 can catch [unreachability]
 issues caused by ASI:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2575

But the compiler builders intentionally leave the rest to external tools, like TSLint which has the `semicolon` rule specifically for this: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/semicolon

Rick can set this rule to `never`, which: "disallows semicolons at the end of every statement *except for when they are necessary*." (!)

Answer (score 4):

Typescript, as a superset of JS, utilises the latter's Automatic Semicolon Insertion. If you want to learn more about where it will be implicitly put, read here -> http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons .

Comment: Better idea: ignore whether or not the translator adds semicolons. They simply aren't needed. They are a waste of time that are allowed so that folks hopelessly habituated to using them won't feel uncomfortable.

Comment: ASI is a hack that was added in to make sloppy code work. You could use written English without periods if you keep it to one sentence per line and, when you deviate from that, otherwise ensure your grammatical structure is not ambiguous. Likewise you can take advantage of ASI so semicolons don't make you feel uncomfortable. In a c-style syntax with free form whitespace, the semicolon is our period. ASI places javascript in an awkward space between freeform and structural whitepsace that creates problematic ambiguities. Everyone has preferences. Dont mistake your own for virtue or correctness.